# Extract the number and increment the value using formulae

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to compare the cell value and extract some number from it and increment that number. While as shown in figure, I want to increment `0` to `1`, this formulae works.

```
=IF(AND(A1 >= "00", A1 <= "99"), LEFT(D1, LEN(D1)-4) & TEXT(VALUE(MID(D1, LEN(D1)-1, 1)) + 1, "0"), "")
```

[image]

But when I try to increment the value from `1` to `2`, this formulae doesnot work.What is wrong in the formulae?

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version? Is it 365?

Comment: @Harun24hr yes, the excel version is 365.

Comment: suggest posting a few more lines of your sample text strings (try to cover as many different scenarios as possible) and then show us the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-

```
=TEXTBEFORE(D1,"-",-1)&"-"&TEXT(--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D1,"-",-1),"_")+1,"0000")&"_"&TEXTAFTER(D1,"_")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time but I tried using the same formuale `=TEXTBEFORE(D1,"-",-1)&"-"&TEXT(--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D1,"-",-1),"_")+1,"0000")&"_"&TEXTAFTER(D1,"_")` but doesnot wrok. D1 value is in format of `T-00-0000-0000_00`. I want to change it to `T-00-0000-0001_00`

Comment: @gretal What do you get error, wrong value?

Comment: It prints  "#NAME?" IN THE CELL.

Comment: @gretal Seems like you don't really have Microsoft `365`. Either that or the formula in your comment is not what is really on your worksheet. Formula works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the text string of type `"T-$$-$$$$-****_$$"` is in `A1`. You need to extract only `****`, and there are always 4 and only 4 of them.

`=VALUE(RIGHT(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_"),1,1),4))`

Step by step:

1. `TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_")` creates from string a 2-cell array divided at `underscore _` symbol.
2. `TAKE(array, 1 , 1)` returns the first row - first column cell of the `array` on step 1.
3. `RIGHT(string, 4)` returns the last 4 symbols of the string. NOTE: If the number of symbols can vary, we will need to add another step for `TEXTSPLIT()` between steps 1 and 2, break the text again at `dash -` symbol and take the cell we need.
4. `VALUE(text)` optional step if you need to convert text to number.